# Virtualization Options on Windows 7 for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am running Windows 7 x64.  I want to make a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 virtual machine so I can try out Sharepoint development.

I have heard that Hyper-V is not supported on Windows 7.

So what is supported on Windows 7?

**Note: I need a product that is free for commercial use or is a Microsoft solution.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find a Microsoft solution for Windows 7 that allows you to virtualise 64-bit guests. If you need a quick virtualisation solution I would use VirtualBox, or if you need a proper virtual server solution I would use VMware.

Comment: Just so you know, out of the box VirtualBox requires you to keep the virtual machine window on your desktop unless you want to play with `vboxheadless`. VMware Server (being "server" oriented) does not.